# Rails 3: Ajax nested resource delete

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I have a nested resource model in my Rails 3 app. It is the standard blog app with posts and comments. I have just started using jQuery etc to make my app more dynamic, I am now struggling to remove comments in the nested model with the link_to helper.

**Comments Model**

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end
```

**Post Model**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments
end
```

In my **Posts/show.html.erb** I have the following bloc that displays all the comments with a link_to helper to delete the comments. This works with HTML but when I added :remote => true, it deleted the parent post instead of the comment! How can I set it up so it deletes only the comment?

```
<% @post.comments.each do |comment| %>
      <%= comment.body %>   
      <%= link_to "Approve", [@post,comment], :method =>:put, :remote=>true %>
      <%= link_to "Delete", [@post,comment], :method =>:delete, :remote=>true %>        
<%end%>
```

Thanks,

Comment: What are the contents of your delete.js.erb file?

Comment: I do not have one yet - @JakeSmith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to have this in your delete action of your Comment class:

```
def delete
    ...
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.js
    end
end
```

Then, in your views/comments directory, you should have a file named delete.js.erb that does your jQuery DOM manipulation (finds the particular comment that you clicked the delete link of and remove it.

Then, your link_to for the delete method in your Posts/show.html.erb file, you can specify the controller and action, and also pass in any data you might need (the parent post so you can refer to it in your jQuery).  You can refer to the first examples section of this site for the syntax on specifying a particular controller and action for a link_to helper [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to).

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I needed to add the format.js to my controller. And create a destroy.js.erb file.

Answer (score 0):

Just check the corresponding action in the controller. 
If there is a render or redirect_to just delete it

it works for me (Rails 4)